# Copying File: ThisWorkbook.Path with FileSystemObject gives Bad Filename or Number error

Tags: excel, vba

So before saving to the current XML file that my VBA code is working on, I want to create a timestamp based backup of the XML file in VBA. This is how I plan to do it:

```
Sub CreateBackup()
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    oldFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DEMO.xml"
    newFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DEMO" & Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & ".xml.bak"
    objFSO.CopyFile oldFilePath, newFilePath
End Sub
```

However, everytime I get a `Bad Filename or Number error`. I have double checked (using the debugger) that my variables are reading the correct filepath with filename. What gives?

Comment: `:` is not allowed in file names.

Comment: Ah! Does `Format` accept `yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is not allowed in file names.

Replace

```
Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

with

```
Format$(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh_mm_ss")
```

for example.

Note that using `Format$()` returns a string instead of a variant (using `Format()`).

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. will accept as answer as soon as allowed.